# How to define Variable similer to Session variable in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to define a variable or object like session, to stored data about each user, and i want to access this object in many pages, 
could u please tell me if there is a way.
thanks

Comment: why wouldn't you use Session ?

Comment: What you want to use is a `Session` variable.

Comment: because i want to store keyValuePair,

Comment: and i want to use an object to provide its class with some usefull methodes to help me later

Comment: @Sum: `Session["X"] = your_KeyValuePair_variable` or `Session["Your_Helper"] = new your_helper_class()` will also work - at least for In-Proc session mode. Are you using some other session mode?

Comment: Just be careful if you're load-balancing and/or using session persistence, that the values added to the session are okay to be serialized.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell Just in case, what kinds of objects can't be serialised well? Is there some interface one should implement for objects to be safely stored in Session vars?

Comment: It depends. Dictionaries don't serialise well, because the hashcodes used for the "buckets" for keys aren't guaranteed to de-serialised properly, but I can't remember if that's the case for the BinarySerializer or just Xml serializer. You should typically mark serialisable objects with the SerializableAttribute, and optionally mark properties with serialisation-specific attributes as necessary. There are interfaces you can implement for even more fine-grained control. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store data in a cookie and then in your codebehind parse the specific cookie into something like a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

But you should use sessions.

**Edit**

IF if's a `KeyValuePair<String,TValue>` you can set `Session[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;`, if not `Session["KVP"] = kvp;`

Comment: None that I know of, simply because you usually don't need this. There is a finished solution, why build another one.

Comment: I think session is probably what you need. Just be aware that there can be issues if you start persisting session state (for example in a load-balanced scenario).

Answer (score 1):

You have onlyy a few choices, really. URL parameters, hidden form inputs, cookies, session (be careful in a load-balanced scenario) or just store/retrieve stuff from a database. RaveDB is bloomin' brilliant for this because it's so fast and document-based.

Answer (score 0):

If u really don't want to use session use Database mind that this is a slow method...

Answer (score 0):

i've had a few situations where I wanted to minimize/eliminate session storage (due to users being on a horrible wifi connection). to handle this situation I used an encrypted query string with only their ID in the string. in the base page I would decrypt the string and pull information I needed from the database. This information would be populated into objects that I defined and since the objects were in the base page I could access the information from any pages that inherited it.